# How to set a breakpoint in gdb for all invocations of a function?

Tags: c++, gdb

I have a third part library function call scattered at a lot of places in my executable. My executable is built using debug symbols, but the third party library does not have the debug symbols, hence I cannot place a breakpoint on the function. I want to put a breakpoint whenever the library function is called, to examine the call stack.
How can I set a breakpoint  at all invocations of a library function call within my executable.

Comment: It seems that the linker would have to know the name->address mapping of the function even without debug symbols, so I can't figure out why you can't put a breakpoint on it. Are you sure it isn't in a shared library that's loaded after you attempt to place the breakpoint?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that the only way is to:

- find any call of this function in your code;
- create a breakpoint in that line;
- run the debugger and stop there;
- write in gdb `nexti` to get to the first function instruction;
- get current eip which will point at the beginning of that function;
- create a new breakpoint at the address pointed by eip;